# How to disable clicking when pointer-events: none CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a content and an overlay which while opened, I want to have the content that is masked scrollable- something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/k8xpchtv/

howver I have a link, inside the masked content which I want to disable clicking when overlay is opened (masked). Only when overlay closed, I want the click to be enabled.

css:

```
.main{
  position: relative;
}
.masked-content {
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
 
}
.mask {
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: default;
    height: 150px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
     z-index: 1000;
     pointer-events: none;
       cursor: not-allowed;
    }
```

html:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="masked-content">This is some text covered by the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents <a href="www.google.com">above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above tents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the mask</div>

  <div>
    <div class="mask">Some contents above the mask</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there any other css property that would allow scrolling on bg when masked, but disable other events?
thx

Comment: `.masked-content a { pointer-events: none; }` ?

Comment: thanks for your answer, but that wont work, it'll disable scrolling also, I want scrolling enabled but click disabled.

Comment: how about a little javascript for that? is that ok? you need to provide more info. when do you want the mask to apply? what's the condition for that?

Comment: This only targets the links, hence the `a` in `.masked-content a`, it's tested and it works

Comment: hi @savageGoat: you;re right and sorry for not being clear before: please check fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/1ebyo352/3/ I gave <a> as a example, but there could be more than just <a> tags in real life scenario and addressing every tag in the css wont be feasible- in the fiddle here - I;ve given some other tags that result in clicking.